# CIDR Overlap in Multi-VPC Envi

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

In a multi-VPC environment under the same account, how does one prevent CIDR overlapping assuming the VPCs are provisioned using CloudFormation? These VPCs may be required to interact with each other in future and hence would be peered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can be accomplished with a [Custom Resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html). Custom resources can run code as a Lambda function, and you should be able to send it the CIDR range that was input by the user. The code would list the VPCs in all regions, and check if the CIDR range of any existing VPC overlaps with the new VPC. If it does, return an error and fail the stack creation. Make sure other resources depend on this custom resource so that nothing is created unless this condition is satisfied.

For an example custom resource, see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/walkthrough-custom-resources-lambda-lookup-amiids.html

Comment: VPCs across accounts can also be peered right ?
So this lambda needs to list down all the CIDR blocks across different AWS accounts and regions ?

Comment: Yes. If that is your set up, then you have to adjust the lambda function accordingly to look through all accounts. You would accomplish this by setting up cross-account roles and making the appropriate STS calls to retrieve credentials for the other accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that VPCs do not have overlapping CIDR blocks.
While creating VPC update the CIDR block in the Cloud Formation template.

The CIDR block cannot be edited after VPC creation. Its better to take precautions before creation of the VPC.

EDIT:

[AWS Transit Gateways](https://aws.amazon.com/transit-gateway/faqs/)

> Q: Can I connect Amazon VPCs with overlapping CIDRs?

> A: AWS Transit Gateway doesn’t support routing between Amazon VPCs with overlapping CIDRs. If you attach a new Amazon VPC that has a CIDR which overlaps with an already attached Amazon VPC, AWS Transit Gateway will not propagate the new Amazon VPC route into the AWS Transit Gateway route table.

Connect all the VPCs to a transit Gateway.

Also checkout VPC Sharing

[AWS VPC Sharing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-sharing.html)

Comment: How do I ensure that? Assume there were 25 VPCs already existing and the 26th is being created. Think a mistake was made while inputting. Is there a way in CloudFormation to know it OOB that there is an existing VPC with an overlapping CIDR?

Comment: Are the VPC's being created in the same AWS account ?

Comment: @NitinRastogi also check out AWS Transit Gateways and VPC Sharing, have added it in the edit section.

Answer (score 0):

> how does one prevent CIDR overlapping assuming the VPCs are provisioned using CloudFormation?

This is part of **architecting and documenting**  your infrastructure. Also you can have only **5 VPC per region** so its not that much to verify, even manually, if your new VPC does not overlap with existing one.

For **automated** solution within CloudFormation, a possible choice would be to look at [custom resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html). The resource could check if the CIDR you use is already taken by other VPC or not. If the CIDR overlaps, the custom resource would signal `FAILURE` and stack creation with the VPC would fail.

Comment: 5 is the soft limit and can be raised to a maximum of 100. I am expecting around 30 od VPCs

Comment: Can also connect multiple accounts and regions and have thousands of VPCS. Consider using an IPAM